# DataGrab Plugin UK Date issue

Tags: ee2, datagrab

I am having issues with importing a CSV into Expression Engine with the DataGrab plugin. Most of the rows are being imported but there is still a small amount that is not.

There are only two columns I am trying to pull in from the CSV. These are the subject and the start date. The start date is in the correct format for the plugin according to the documentation.

"2013-05-01 15:05:00"

But the plugin is seeing it as:

"2013-01-05 15:05:00"

Any ideas as to why this is happening? The full row of the CSV file is below for reference.

"Athletics Match - Years 8 & 10 - at Sohan VC - 3.05pm - 6.15pm","Publish on Website|Sporting Activity|Year 10|Year 8","2013-05-01 15:05:00","2013-05-01 18:15:00","0","Soham","2013-04-22 15:19:36","2013-04-29 12:30:15"

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Dave